# Reveal table content in the style of google images

Tags: jquery, html-table, tooltip

I'm trying to get a custom catalogue tooltip working on my site, I wanted to make it look and operate the same kind of way Google Image search does, i.e. you click on an image, then info about the image appears in the row underneath it, you click on something else and then the first row disappears, revealing the second row.

I've never been great at jQuery but I've managed to get it so that it is pulling in the cells content which I've set to hidden with CSS into a row underneath the cell you click on, but I don't know where to go in terms of deleting the content once the row has been populated when you click on something.

I've made a [fiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/w3nHL/) which shows the basic thing I'm looking for and where I am at, but I'm not sure where to go from here

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="catalogue">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 1 content</div></td>
            <td><a href="#">Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 2 content</div></td>
            <td><a href="#">Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 3 content</div></td>
            <td><a href="#">Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 4 content</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 5 content</div></td>
            <td><a href="#">Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 6 content</div></td>
            <td><a href="#">Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 7 content</div></td>
            <td><a href="#">Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 8 content</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 9 content</div></td>
            <td><a href="#">Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 10 content</div></td>
            <td><a href="#">Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 11 content</div></td>
            <td><a href="#">Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 12 content</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.catalogue {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
}

.catalogue td {
    height:80px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#e0e0e0;
}

.catalogue td a {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#000;
}

.catalogue .tooltip td {
    width:100%;
    padding:1.5em;
    text-align:left;
}

.catalogue .content {
    display:none;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.container').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    cell_content = $(this).parent().find('.content').text();
    button_row = $(this).closest('tr');
    button_row.after('<tr class="tooltip"><td colspan="4">' + cell_content + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: If there's ever only going to be one .tooltip row, you can simply delete it before adding it back in: $('.tooltip').remove();   right before your buttons_row.after()..

Comment: Ah! I knew it couldn't be that difficult to remove it, I thought the command was .clear();

Comment: I have now tried to make it move up and down using slideToggle, it seems to have problems animating, it just disappears after a certain time using slideToggle, is that something to do with the fact its a table?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my layout from a table to a series of aligning divs, which just works so much better. I have managed to write the Javascript so that it is able to read how many items are in each row, and will then loop through the items before appending a new div underneath that with a clearing spacer.

This updated version is modified from a live version I have working, although I intend to update it in the future so that it pulls the tooltip information in as an AJAX query, as it is a little archaic in its current method. If anyone wants to modify or improve upon this code, please do so :)

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w3nHL/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="catalogue">
            <div class="catalogue-item"><a>Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 1 content</div></div>
            <div class="catalogue-item"><a>Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 2 content</div></div>
            <div class="catalogue-item"><a>Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 3 content</div></div>
            <div class="catalogue-item"><a>Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 4 content</div></div>
            <div class="catalogue-item"><a>Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 5 content</div></div>
            <div class="catalogue-item"><a>Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 6 content</div></div>
            <div class="catalogue-item"><a>Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 7 content</div></div>
            <div class="catalogue-item"><a>Click</a><div class="content">This is Cell 8 content</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.container').delegate('.catalogue-item a', 'click', function() {
    // Sets variables about the settings of the row and cell clicked
    catalogue_container = $('.container');
    catalogue_width = catalogue_container.width();
    cell = $(this).closest('div.catalogue-item');
    cell_width = cell.width();
    cell_content = cell.find('.content').html();
    cell_position = Math.floor(cell.position().left / cell_width);

    // Returns possible total cells available in container width
    row_cells = Math.floor(catalogue_width / cell_width);

    for (var i = cell_position; i < row_cells; i++) {
        cell = cell.next('.catalogue-item');
    }

    cell_prefix = '<div class="clearfix catalogue-tooltip">';
    cell_suffix = '</div>';

    // Checks to see if there are any tooltips already entered
    if (typeof old_content !== 'undefined') {
        // Checks to see if the tooltip is already out
        if ($('.catalogue-tooltip').length && cell_content != old_content) {
            old_tooltip = $('.catalogue-tooltip');
            $('.catalogue-tooltip').slideToggle(800, function() {
                old_tooltip.remove();
                cell.after(cell_prefix + cell_content + cell_suffix);
                old_content = cell_content;
                $('.catalogue-tooltip').slideToggle(800);
            });
        } 
    } else {
        cell.after(cell_prefix + cell_content + cell_suffix);
        old_content = cell_content;
        $('.catalogue-tooltip').slideToggle(800);
    }
});
```